# How to import a.b in python?

Tags: python, import

I try to use `__init__.py`.

My directory:

```
 sam@sam-M51Kr:~/code/python$ tree
 .
 |-- __init__.py
 |-- lib
 |   |-- __init.py
 |   |-- sam_lib.py
 |   `-- sam_lib.pyc
 `-- test.py

 1 directory, 5 files
 sam@sam-M51Kr:~/code/python$
```

All my `__init__.py` are empty.

My `lib/sam_lib.py`:

```
k='hello!'
```

My `test.py`:

```
import python.lib.sam_lib
print(sam_lib.k)
```

When I run:

```
 sam@sam-M51Kr:~/code/python$ python test.py 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
     import python.lib.sam_lib
 ImportError: No module named python.lib.sam_lib
 sam@sam-M51Kr:~/code/python$
```

How to solve it with syntax `import x.x`?

Should I use `__init.py__`?

==============================

I revise `lib/__init.py` to `lib/__init__.py`

I try to revise `test.py`:

```
 from . import lib.sam_lib as sam_lib
 print(sam_lib.k)
```

It will cause an error:

```
 sam@sam-M51Kr:~/code/python$ python test.py 
   File "test.py", line 1
     from . import lib.sam_lib as sam_lib
                      ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 sam@sam-M51Kr:~/code/python$
```

And it is ok when I revise to:

```
 import lib.sam_lib as sam_lib
 print(sam_lib.k)
```

Comment: It should be `__init__.py`, not `__init.py__` or `__init.py`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is wrong at different levels

- The file `__init.py` should be `__init__.py`
- In python, you need to access object with its relative path: when you do `import a.b.c` the
  `c.x` object must be accessed using `a.b.c.x` unless you used `import
  a.b.c as c`

To fix the code, use:

```
import lib.sam_lib as sam_lib
print(sam_lib.k)
```

Note that `import python.lib.sam_lib as sam_lib` or `from .lib import sam_lib`would have worked if test.py is imported as a module as in `import python.test` from a code in the upper level directory, not when you run test.py directly.